# If we re-define this function could it be bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, analysis, cryptography

According to this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter-Wagner/publication/222662780_Unmediated_communication_with_partially_verifiable_types/links/5a38f1d2aca272a6ec1f13df/Unmediated-communication-with-partially-verifiable-types.pdf) in page $4$ where it describes the encryption scheme where a cipher function is defined as it follows
$$\rho:T\times Y \to X$$
such that $|Y|\geq |T|$, where $y\in Y$ is the key and $x\in X$ a code. $t$, $x$ ,$y$ are variables that are defined in the corresponding fields $T$, $X$, $Y$ and $\rho(\cdot,y)$ is a bijection namely every pair of $(x,y)$ is associated with only one $t$ (i.e. $\rho(t,y)=x$).

Could we re-define the $\rho$ function in the following way and still be bijective? That is

$$\rho:T\times(\Pi_{i=1}^K Y_i)\to X$$
where $(y_1,y_2.\cdots,y_K)$ is family of i.i.d. uniform random variables such that the $(K+1)$- tuple $(x,y_1,y_2,\cdots, y_K)$, is associated with only one $t$.

Comment: What do you mean by "random" variables? How do you even connect encryption with random variables? There's nothing random about encryption. It may look like random noise, but it is far from.

Comment: @freakish I can not understand what is your point. I ask something specific about the function $\rho$. Also you can check the paper that I cite above for what every variable stands for. It is just a small paragraph in page $4$...

Comment: To be more precise in the first case, as the cipher is defined it occurs that there is only one key, that is $y$. We could use a cipher with more that one keys in a scheme with many players. Say in one player wants to share his secret $s$ with a group of $5$ players he will send one part, $x$ to some players and the other part $y$ to the others but no player will obtain both parts that give the secret. So it would be betted that there is a scheme of a cipher with 4 keys $y_1$, $y_2,$ $y_3$ and $y_4$ and one player takes the code $x$ ($5$ in total). Only if all $5$ parts combine give the $s$

Comment: No, the product is not helpful here, consider $(2,3)$ then $(3,2)$ will result in the same key for the encryption, however, they are different inputs. You might consider x-or...

Comment: @kelalaka by x-or you mean how?

Comment: @kelalaka your answer means that $\rho$ is not a bijection in the second case right?

Comment: Nope, X-or will not work, too. Sorry. Yes, it is not.

Comment: @kelalaka I am searching for days something that might work :P if you have anything else to propose...even totally different to this I am open to new ideas

Comment: Well, the $Y_i$'s total space must not be larger than the keyspace. Then the rest is obvious, partitioning... This is, however, might not what you want. Besides this, even larger the block cipher still is PRP but your keyspace extension needs to be considered. If you want to is Shared Secret, then you don't define it in this way to complicate the case. The key is shared, when needed construct it and use it with the PRP.

Comment: @kelalaka but $Y$ is the key space...and what is a PRP?

Comment: PRP is Pseudo Random Permutation, we use it for Block cipher's security; not easy to prove that a block cipher is a PRP, however, no one showed that AES is not a PRP and mostly we believe that AES is a PRP. Yes, $Y$ is the keyspace that you can share it with SSS.

Comment: Also, the block size can be larger than the key size like DES has 64-bit block size and 56-bit key size. ChaCha on the other hand is a PRF (Pseudo-Random Function) that internally uses CTR mode of operation has at most 256-bit key size with 512 bit output.

Comment: @kelalaka by saying I can share it with SSS, you mean that I can keep the assumption about the cipher as in the first case and then only about $Y$ i can use the SSS? No need to change anything for $\rho$ after defining it I can use a simple SSS for $Y$?

Comment: can you give a paper that has a simple formulation about  a proof that a block cipher is a PRP?

Comment: Yes, that's it. SSS has perfect secrecy and sharing the key has no relation to increasing the keyspace. Look for  Luby and Rackoff construction...

Comment: @kelalaka Let us assume that $f:T\times Y_1\times\cdots\times Y_K\to X$ such that 

$$f(t,y_1,\cdots,t_k)=x_1\oplus x_2\oplus\cdots\oplus x_k$$, where the $K$ pairs $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, ... , $(x_k,y_k)$ are associated with only one $t$. Could this be an equivalent mapping of $\rho$, that extends it in the case of $k$ keys and $f$ is bijective?

Comment: Input space != output space....

Comment: @kelalaka which means? in mathematical formulation?